# Use relative paths after .htaccess redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, errordocument

The `.htaccess` in my root directory is

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

ErrorDocument 404 /error/index.html
```

And in `error/` the `.htaccess` is

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

When I open `error/index.html` in a browser normally everything is fine, but when opening after a 404 redirection the images don't load unless I specify them as an absolute path. I presume even though the file is `/error/index.html`, it is being run in the directory from which the user is redirected, which does not contain the desired image files (which are located in `error/`). Is there any way to use paths relative to the `ErrorDocument` after `.htaccess` redirection?

Answer (score 2):

While the better fix is always to use absolute path but you can also use `<base>` tag.

Try adding this in your page's HTML header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. The `/` seems to specify the server root, rather than the current directory.

Comment: What is actual correct path of your CSS/js/image files?

Comment: They are in the same folder as the ErrorDocument.

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is ErrorDocument line you ate using and where is htaccess located etc etc